# How to run multiple for loop with multiple cat input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop

I have seed file with below content.

```
$cat seed.txt
macmachine,192.168.2.4,29772
windowsmachine,192.168.2.5,29772
$
```

When I run for loop first `$x` will cat first field of first line that is `macmachine` from seed file and "do" run second for loop and this will cat second field of first line and so on...

Here is my for loop

```
for x in `cat seed.txt |cut -d ',' -f1`; do
    for y in `cat seed.txt |cut -d ',' -f2`; do
        curl -v -H -X GET -H "X-TEST-Request-Id: Domain-$x" http://$y:8080/static/test/$y.jsp;
    done;
done
```

The problem is it runs 8 times. If I remove first line from seed file it will run only once.

I'm sure something is wrong with the loop, but I'm not able to trace that.
Please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: 8=2 x 2 x 2;  are you sure you don't have `for z in  `cat seed.txt |cut -d ',' -f3`; do`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `cat` (UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`; search for it); `cut` is quite capable of reading files.

Comment: With two lines of data, you should be getting the `curl` executed 4 times.  The outer loop has `x` set to `macmachine` then `windowsmachine`; the inner loop has `y` set to `192.168.2.4` and then `192.168.2.5`.  Did you omit a loop on `z` picking up the last column?  That would give you 8 loops, but the code doesn't show that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler last column is not required. only starting 2 field is required.

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A seed.txt`

Answer (score 1):

When you want to proces one line after another, do something like

```
while IFS=, read -r x y z; do
   curl -v -H -X GET -H "X-TEST-Request-Id: Domain-$x" "http://$y:8080/static/test/$z.jsp"
done < seed.txt
```

Comment: Walter thanks for your prompt reply. Where i need define "cat seed.txt |cut -d ',' -f1". also one more query how i can add if condition.. the condition is if first line curl is success then proceed to next curl if failed then break.

Comment: How i can pick random field?

Comment: When `curl` (or most other commands) fail, `$?` will be set to a value different from 0 (until the next command). You can add `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then break; fi` after the curl line. Shorter is appending `|| break` at the end of the `curl` command.

Comment: What do you mean with random field? Field of a line? Linenumber> Something else? For a random value between 0 and 3, use `(( myrandom = RANDOM % 3 )) ; echo ${myrandom}`.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to make something like this script does?

```
for x in `cat seed.txt` ; do
curl -v -H -X GET -H "X-TEST-Request-Id: Domain-$(echo $x | cut -f 1 -d ',')" http://$(echo $x | cut -f 2 -d ','):8080/static/test/$(echo $x | cut -f 2 -d ',').jsp
done
```

"for" statement reads each line of file in its respective iteration cycle (two times in this case) and assign a line (or text item separated by spaces to be precise) from file to x variable so many times as many text items are in the file. The thing that have to be done next is to split input line(x variable) onto substring variables and supply them to curl, which is done by the "echo|cut" command.